# Observe removed objects in lists

Tags: java, javers

We are currently using JaVers 3.0.0. Suppose we have the following two entities A and B. And A keeps track of some Bs in a list.

```
@Entity
@TypeName("A")
public class A {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private List<B> items;

    public A() {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public A(int id) {
        this();
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<B> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<B> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

}
```

And here is our rather simple class B.

```
@Entity
@TypeName("B")
public class B {

    @Id
    private int id;

    public B() {
    }

    public B(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Lets commit three changes to an object of type A:

- Commit object with empty list
- Commit object with two added Bs
- Commit object with one B removed

After that I want to observe changes on B.

```
Javers javers = JaversBuilder
                .javers()
                .build();

A a = new A(1);
javers.commit("foo@example.com", a);

a.getItems().add(new B(1));
a.getItems().add(new B(2));
javers.commit("foo@example.com", a);

a.getItems().remove(0);
javers.commit("foo@example.com", a);

List<Change> changes = javers.findChanges(
QueryBuilder.byClass(B.class)
            .build());

String changelog = javers.processChangeList(changes, new SimpleTextChangeLog());
System.out.println(changelog);
```

The output says zero changes. I was expecting to see a removed object since B is an entity and has an Id. What am I missing?

**Edit**
Thanks for answering in the comments so far. Maybe I wasn't detailed enough. Sorry about that.

What I am trying to query is all the changes on A and all the changes on B. I only commit A, but maybe that is the problem? Should I track A and B?

Comment: But no B changed. Did you try `A.class` instead just out of curiosity? Or used B.setId ? I am sure you'd get change logs then.

Comment: @Fildor That is true, a single B did not change, but one was removed from the list of A. I thought I could find them this way.

Comment: "a single B did not change, but one was removed from the list of A." then you have to query that instance of A. A hint for you should be that you only commit `a` ...

Comment: @fildor But if B has additional properties and some change during commits to A, my Jql query would find them. However removing is not found.

Comment: Because removing is a change to the list containing the removed object. One could argue if it is to the removed object itself.

Comment: no b has been committed. I deleted my comment. Query a and it should work

Comment: "Should I track A and B?" - I guess so.

Comment: Putting an annotation by itself does nothing. It depends on the tool that process them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javers.compare()` and `javers.commit()` don't work in the same way.
`compare()` simply compares two object graphs, without any context.
That's why you could expect `ObjectRemoved` on the change list when comparing graphs.

But `commit()` is for auditing changes.
Since you've mapped both classes as Entities, they are independent. B objects can't be marked as deleted just because they are no longer referenced by A objects.

The only way to mark them as deleted (and to have ObjectRemoved change) is by calling `commitShallowDelete()`